# How to adjust the orientation of UIViewControllerWrapperView (in IOS7)?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, orientation

**Background:** The application is an iPad app running in Landscape only. When upgrading the app to Xcode 5 and running in the IOS7 simulator, I noticed that some buttons on the right side of the screen were not fully active. i.e. only a fraction of the left side of the button was clickable.

**Observation:** Running the same source code in IOS6 and IOS7 simulators, and viewing the view hierarchy using the REVEAL tool, I can see that the dimensions of the UIViewControllerWrapperView (the parent of my top level view controller) are landscape for IOS6 (1024x768), but portrait for IOS7.

I am trying to find a way to set the frame of the UIViewControllerWrapperView to the correct dimensions. In the view controller's viewDidLoad method, I tried to get a reference to self.view.superview, but it returns nil.

Can anybody explain; a) why the UIViewControllerWrapperView's frame is in the wrong orientation when running in IOS7 and not IOS6, and more importantly b) how to make it right?

Answer (score 7):

Are you using a UITabBarController? We were having **exactly** the same issue and got it working by adding this on the UITabBarController:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // fix for iOS7 bug in UITabBarController
    self.selectedViewController.view.superview.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Why? [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156979/ios7-setting-selectedindex-of-uitabbarcontroller-breaks-touch-events-along-rig/19223670#19223670)

Comment: Thanks for this. We had a QA lab iPad still on iOS 7.0.1, and for some reason we felt the issue needed fixing. GAH!