# ECSlidingViewController landscape 768x768px

Tags: ios, iphone, ecslidingviewcontroller

i use ECSlidingViewController within my iPad app.

Everything works fine except in landscape mode.

The touchable part of the screen is only almost 768x768px :

[image]

When the app launches it is not possible to tap buttons in the green rectangle.

Yet the topViewController view frame and bounds are {{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}.

I should clarify that ECSlidingViewController is not the initial view controller but an item of a UITabBarController.

[image]

Comment: lefakir - what, precisely, is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more general problem (ie UITabBarController on iPad): [iOS7 - Setting selectedIndex of UITabBarController breaks touch events along right-hand edge of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156979/ios7-setting-selectedindex-of-uitabbarcontroller-breaks-touch-events-along-rig/19407311#19407311)