# iOS 8 right side of view not clickable

Tags: ios, view, ios8, viewcontroller

I have an app that was developed for iOS7. Now when i run the app in iOS8 there's an issue where the right side of the view in landscape is not clickable.

It's the same issue as described here: [iOS 7 When Rotating View in Tab Bar, Right Side of View is Not Clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923674/ios-7-when-rotating-view-in-tab-bar-right-side-of-view-is-not-clickable)

But i have no TabBar within the app, not even a NavigationBar in my first view where this issue appears.

I have tried to use this code in viewDidLoad in many different viewcontrollers, but no success.

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Assign the same properties to your inside subviews, for example in the reference link, they have UITextView.

Comment: For example, if you have UIWebview then, self.myWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.myWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the view frame as static like,

view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768); and set background colour of view and check it, it only covered with half the mainview. For orientation (both portrait and landscape) need to change the frame as static (width and height).